# Module for CKEditor that provides a button to check for broken links

Tags: 9, wysiwyg

Are there any modules for Drupal 9 that provide a button for CKeditor that allows the user to check for broken links before saving the content?

I imagine it working like this:

1. The user goes to a node and begins to add or edit text in a textarea
2. After the user enters text, the user can go to the CKEditor toolbar and click a button to check links they have entered to see if they return HTTP 404 responses.
3. After finding the broken links, the user can fix the broken links before saving the content

Comment: I don't think so, and in any case, CKEditor is about to get switched from 4 to 5 (which requires new plugins) in Drupal 10, so it's probably not a good investment to find something for CKEditor 4 anyway.  CKEditor 5 has a mostly ignored feature request here: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/1592

Comment: I wonder if there are any accessibility checkers which might check for 404s

Comment: The w3c validator checks for broken links and can be run as a CI image: https://github.com/validator/validator.  But that's obviously off topic for this site.